# PHP: Funções, Parâmetros, SOAP

Tags: php, funções, soap

Eu tenho o seguinte código com duas funções:

```
public function getClientTemplates(){
    $client_id = 31;

    $this->Send('client_get', compact(array('client_id')));

}
```

---

```
public function Send($action, $post){

    extract($post);

    try {
        $data = $this->soap->$action($post);
    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        $this->addError('ISPConfig said: SOAP Error. '.$e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

Eu tenho uma chamada SOAP que necessita de alguns parâmetros, mas não tenho como saber quantos parâmetros a função da vez pede.

Como está ai no código eu compacto e extraio as variáveis, mas não sei como envia-las sem saber quais e os nomes delas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no seu método `Send()`, você pode tratar o retorno de `__getFunctions` para obter a lista de argumentos necessários. Com este retorno você pode criar um hash onde cada argumento é uma chave. Depois disto de um merge neste hash criado com o seu `compact`.

Talvez não seja a melhor solução, mas na falta de algo melhor é uma opção.

ex. ("de cabeça" e não testado pois estou sem PHP aqui e não programo PHP há muito tempo):

```
public function Send($action, $post){

  extract($post);

  $methods = $this->soap->__getFunctions();
  foreach ($methods as $method) {
    preg_match_all('/[ \t\r\n]*[ \t\r\n]?(.+)[ \t\r\n]*\(([^\)]*)\)/', $method, $matches);
    $method_name = $matches[2];
    $method_args = $matches[3];
    if ($method_name == $action) {
      try {
        $data = $this->soap->$action(array_merge($method_args, $post));
      } catch (SoapFault $e) {
        $this->addError('ISPConfig said: SOAP Error. '.$e->getMessage());
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: É uma solução válida sim, valeu Daniel